# $index is fixed for all pages using dir-paginate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, dirpagination

I am using dirPaginate directive for pagination in my Angular App.
its working fine but the problem is I am showing 10 records per page but on every page the $index is repeating same (1-10) on each page.
it should be 11-20,21-30 and so on for the next pages.help me how to fix it.
this is my code

```
<tbody dir-paginate="wagedtl in listWagemasterdtls | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | filter : detailsfilter |itemsPerPage:10">
<tr><td class="hidden-xs">{{ wagedtl.wageTypeMstrID}}</td><td>{{wagedtl.wageTypeMstrNm}}</td></tr> 
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in my way.
I called a function on page change by on-page-change event of dir-pagination-controls and sent 'newPageNumber'

```
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" on-page-change='indexCount(newPageNumber)'></dir-pagination-controls>
```

in controller I used this logic in function

```
$scope.indexCount = function(newPageNumber){
    $scope.serial = newPageNumber * 10 - 9;
}
```

And binded the 'serial' with $index in html

```
<td>{{ $index + serial}}</td>
```

By default newPageNumber would be undefined.
So  I just kept the default value of 'serial' equals 1. in beginning of controller

```
$scope.serial = 1;
```

May be it's not the best way but my problem is solved now...:D

Answer (score 4):

That's how ng-repeat, which is used by dir-paginate, works. I think it should be 0-9 instead of 1-10 though.

To calculate the actual index throughout pages, you can use `current-page` attribute to set the current page to a property.

```
<tbody dir-paginate="..." current-page="currentPage">
```

Then you can use the property in template

```
$index + currentPage * 10
```

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/blob/master/src/directives/pagination/README.md

Comment: this expression is showing 'NaN' :
what to do now??

Comment: Edited the my answer to use `current-page` attribute to bind the current page number to a scope property.

Comment: With this my table body is gone totally invisible but I can see pagination after table-header and when I'm clicking on page '2'. I can see table body now but the index is starting from 20-29. which should be 10-19.
But thanks i got the index count.I can use it for my requirement.
but
Do I need to set a default value of currentPage to make my first page visible.

Comment: Thanks Man. Problem solved.
I just kept the default value of 'currentPage=1' and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

set  itemsPerPage's value using $scope variable.

```
<tr dir-paginate="item in allProductData" itemsPerPage:itemPerPage" >
```

add a function in `on-page-change`

```
 <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" on-page-change='indexCount(newPageNumber)'
                                                 direction-links="true"
                                                 boundary-links="true">
 </dir-pagination-controls>
```

then make this function in javascript file:

```
$scope.serial = 1;
$scope.itemPerPage=5
$scope.indexCount = function(newPageNumber){
  $scope.serial = newPageNumber * $scope.itemPerPage - ($scope.itemPerPage-1);
}
```

You can change the `itemsPerPage`'s value by changing `$scope.itemPerPage` variable.

That's all. Now you will get your page index in a continuous process.